# Image uploaded to dynamic form input is duplicated in other inputs

Tags: image, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a form where users can add multiple images, and I'm trying to dynamically create new image input fields when the addItemForm is triggered.
First, I try to create a v-for loop through all the item in the form so when the event is trigger, a new item will be pushed into the loop, then all images are pushed into the array 'imageListImage' and I loop through that array again to print out all the images. The delete function is to delete the image from the array.

```
    <b-row v-for="(item, index_loop) in form.contents" :key="index_loop">
        <input type="file" :v-model="form.contents[index_loop].file" @change="ttrs($event, false, 'listImage')" />
        <div v-for="(src, index) in imageListImage" :key="index">
            <label class="delete-img" @click="deleteImage(index, 'listImage')">
                <p>
                    delete
                </p>
            </label>
            <img v-if="src.isImage" :v-model="form.contents[index_loop].images" :src="src.url" />
        </div>

        <label v-if="index_loop == 0" @click="addItemForm">
            Add block
        </label>
    </b-row>
```

However, I'm facing an issue where when I upload an image to the first input field, it duplicates the image to all the newly created input fields.
This is the some of the methods that I used

```
data() {
        return {
            form: {
                contents: [{
                    file: [],
                    images: [],
                }, ],
            },
            imageListImage: [],
            listImage: [],
        };
    },

    methods: {
        // add a new form block
        addItemForm() {
            const newItem = {
                file: [],
                images: [],
            };
            this.form.contents.push(newItem);
        },

        // Read the data from the images that was inserted
        ttrs(e, flag = false, name) {
            let datas = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            this.readFile(datas, flag, name);
        },

        // Read all the data of the images that is inserted into a form
        async readFile(files, flag, name) {
            var vm = this;
            for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
                let file = {
                    isImage: true,
                    url: "",
                    no: 0,
                    is_thumbnail: true
                };
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    file.url = event.target.result;
                    if (name == "listImage") {
                        if (flag) {
                            vm.imageListImage.push(file);
                        } else {
                            vm.imageListImage.push(file);
                        }
                    }
                };
                if (name == "listImage") {
                    this.listImage.push({
                        file: files[index],
                        name: files[index].name
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
            }
        },
        // delete an image from a form
        deleteImage(index, name) {
            if (name == "listImage") {
                this.listImage.splice(index, 1);
                this.imageListImage.splice(index, 1);
            }
        },

    },
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Please create a Minimum Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What you posted is not sufficient to repro. Without a *runnable* [mcve] the question is *unanswerable*, therefore useless to anyone, including yourself, therefore *off-topic*. In current form, no answer is possible, never-mind a canonical one, regardless of how much reputation is offered.

Comment: I have changed my post to a runnable mimal reproducible example and also test it on the vue.js playground. Thank you for your comments @Fanoflix, sorry for being unclear since I'm still not familiar to ask question here

Comment: Can you share the Vue playground that you created?

Comment: @Fanoflix here is the link https://playcode.io/1454030

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what is currently happening:

- you have a list of `form.contents`, each with their own list of files and images
- you have a list of files (`imageListImage`), where you want to collect all files (currently all files and images from every item in `form.contents`)
- when files are added (through `readFile()` via `ttrs()`), you put them into the `imageListImage`
- in your template, you loop over the items in `form.contents` and print the collected list each time, giving you the duplication

But I think you want to do:

- keep the list of `form.contents`
- add files to the corresponding item in `form.contents`
- at each iteration in the template, print for each `form.contents` the files belonging to the item (so no more duplication)
- turn the collection `imageListImage` into a computed property

Here is a snippet with this (abstracted) behavior:

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup(){
    const formItems = ref([])
    const addFormItem = () => {
      formItems.value.push({files: []})
    }
    addFormItem()
    const addToFormItem = (item, file) => item.files.push(file)
    const inputData = ref([])
    const allFiles = computed(() => formItems.value.flatMap(item => item.files)) 
    
    return {formItems, addFormItem, addToFormItem, inputData, allFiles}  
  }
}
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addFormItem">Add form item</button>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="(formItem, index) in formItems" :key="index">
    <div>
      Form Item {{ index + 1}}
      <input v-model="inputData[index]">
      <button
        :disabled="!inputData[index] || allFiles.includes(inputData[index])"
        @click="addToFormItem(formItem, inputData[index]); inputData[index] = ''"
      >Add</button>
    </div>
    
    <i v-if="formItem.files.length === 0">No files yet</i>
    <ul>
      <li v-else v-for="file in formItem.files" :key="file">{{file}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  
  <div>All files: {{ allFiles }}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Does that make sense? Does it work for you?

Comment: What I need is something like this: when I add 2 images into form item 1, they will show right below the form item 1. After that, I add 2 new images into form item 2, they will show right below form item 2. It is somewhat like an array in an array,

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the answer describes, isn't it? Have you looked at the snippet?